# java.util.MissingResourceException : Can't find bundle for base name configuration-dev, locale fr_FR

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to migrate a `webservice` from seam to eap6 ( `java ee 6`) using jboss6 then, the `webservice` become a simple `ejb`, this new `ejb` need a properties file named `configuration-dev`,

I put this file in `ejbModule/src/main/resources` but it give me `java.util.MissingResourceException` : Can't find bundle for base name `configuration-dev`, `locale fr_FR` exception.

any idea about where I should put the file.
thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you load your bundle? Why are you using a ResourceBundle instead of a simple properties file? (Do you really need localized configuration?)

Comment: What I want is to have a file X.properties where the resource bundle can fin data ( as messages or others ) and use this data inside the app(ejb app), so these file could be packaged when the app is deployed